# Google drive for desktop - how can I remove the virtual drives?

Tags: google-drive

I just transitioned from Backup & Sync to Google Drive for Desktop, and now the drive app has created a virtual drive in my desktop. Within this virtual drive there is a link to my drive folder in the other drive. I chose the Mirror option, not the Stream, so there is nothing in the virtual drive except that link.

Is there a way to remove this virtual drive, and just have the drive folder synced, like it did before?

Comment: At the moment it seems the answer is no. I am trying to rename these virtual drives and cannot even do that.